# Typescript compiler not emitting errors in browser environment

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, compiler-warnings

I was making a code editor for typescript that runs within browser. For transpilation, i decided to use the typescript compiler (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/5.1.6/typescript.min.js)

I transpiles to javascript, but is not emitting errors such as type errors, etc. The compiler I am using runs in a browser environment.

This is the typescript code before compiling
[Raw typescript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PivnA.jpg)

This is the code after compiling to javascript
[Compiled typescript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkcUK.jpg)

It should have raised some errors.

How do i enable the errors? Do i need to toggle some compiler options or do I need to use a different compiler?

For the code editor, you can find it at devnuts.surge.sh (for more clarity on what i am trying to make)

Thanks

I've done some research on it but the most i could find was errors in nodejs environment.
I tried toggling the compiler options for emitting errors but didn't help.

Comment: Don't post code as images. Use the code block and post it as text in your question.